# evaluating some limits with $\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I don't understand how to prove these results.

$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{\ln{x}}{x} = 0$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}}x\ln{x} = 0$

Comment: Do you know L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: Yes (well I just lloked it up but it seems pretty simple)

Comment: Apply it and you will find this limit is also simple.

Comment: If you have proved the first, the second follows easily, and vice-versa. Let  $x=1/t$. Then  $\ln(x)=\ln(1/t)=-\ln t$. As $x\to\0^+$, $t\to\infty$ and $x\sin(x)=-\frac{\ln t}{t}\to 0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't see how you go from "As $x\to 0^{+}$, $t\to\infty$" to $x\sin{x}=-\dfrac{\ln{t}}{t}→0$

Comment: @Ghuizing, Andre meant $x\ln x = - \frac{\ln t}{t}$. It's just a typo.

Comment: Ok thanks, I begin to understand

Comment: @Ghuizing: Thanks, I was typing blind, little screen, full sunshine.

Comment: oh so you aren't in France I suppose ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { x }{ { b }^{ x } } =0,b>1\quad  } $$ then for enough big $x$ : 
$$\frac { 1 }{ { b }^{ x } } <\frac { x }{ { b }^{ x } } <1$$
denote $b=e^{ \varepsilon }$ for small arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$ then we get:
$$\frac { 1 }{ { e }^{ \varepsilon x } } <\frac { x }{ e^{ \varepsilon x } } <1$$ or $$1<x<{ e }^{ \varepsilon x }$$ take the natural logarithm of both sides,we get $$\\ 0<\ln { x } <\varepsilon x$$ from this for enough big $x $  we finally get $$0<\frac { \ln { x }  }{ x } <\varepsilon $$

Comment: Wha do you mean by enough big $n$?

Comment: you should know definition of limit,then you will understand

Comment: Yeah but you don't use $n$ at all, you use $x$. So maybe you should say for big enough $x$

Comment: ahhh, yes you are right really,thanks for observation)

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to present an approach to evaluating these limits that forgoes use of L'Hospital's Rule.  Here, we begin by using the following definition of the exponential function $e^x$.

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n \tag 1$$

Then, it is straightforward to show from $(1)$ that for $x>0$

$$e^x\ge \left(1+\frac x2\right)^2 \tag 2$$

Inasmuch as $\log x$ is the inverse of $e^x$, then we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{e^x} \tag 3$$

From $(3)$ we have the inequality

$$0\le \frac{x}{e^x} \le \frac{x}{\left(1+\frac x2\right)^2} $$

which by the squeeze theorem implies that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x}{e^x}=0$$

which was to be shown!

---

**NOTE:**

We remark that the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}x\log x$ can be shown to be equivalent to the limit $-\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x}$ through the transformation $x\to 1/x$ and use of the identity $\log (1/x)=-\log x$.  Therefore,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x\log x=0$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.